# How to count subgroups of categorical data in a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"shops": ["shop1", "shop2", "shop3", "shop4", "shop5", "shop6"], "franchise" : ["franchise_A", "franchise_A", "franchise_A", "franchise_A", "franchise_B", "franchise_B"],"items" : ["dog", "cat", "dog", "dog", "bird", "fish"]})
df = df[["shops", "franchise", "items"]]
print(df)

   shops    franchise items
0  shop1  franchise_A   dog
1  shop2  franchise_A   cat
2  shop3  franchise_A   dog
3  shop4  franchise_A   dog
4  shop5  franchise_B  bird
5  shop6  franchise_B  fish
```

So, each row is a unique sample `shop1`, `shop2`, etc. whereby each sample belongs to a subgroup `franchise_A`, `franchise_B`, `franchise_C`, etc. 
In the `items` column, there are only four categorical values possible: `dog`, `cat`, `fish`, `bird`. My motivation is to create a barplot of the number of `dog`, `cat`, `fish`, `bird` for each "franchise".

I would like the output to be

```
franchise        dogs    cats    birds    fish
franchise_A      3       1       0        0
franchise_B      0       0       1        1
```

I believe I first have to use `groupby()`, e.g.

```
df.groupby("franchise").count()
             shops  items
franchise                
franchise_A      4      4
franchise_B      2      2
```

But I'm not sure how I count the number of items for each franchise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), thanks [Nickil Maveli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563209/how-to-count-subgroups-of-categorical-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe#comment72260873_42563259):

```
from collections import Counter

print (df.groupby("franchise")['items'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0))
items        bird  cat  dog  fish
franchise                        
franchise_A     0    1    3     0
franchise_B     1    0    0     1
```

Another solutions with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print (pd.crosstab(df["franchise"], df['items']))
items        bird  cat  dog  fish
franchise                        
franchise_A     0    1    3     0
franchise_B     1    0    0     1
```

---

```
print (df.pivot_table(index="franchise", columns='items', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0))
items        bird  cat  dog  fish
franchise                        
franchise_A     0    1    3     0
franchise_B     1    0    0     1
```

Comment: `value_counts()` instead of `Counter` would really fasten the whole thing up.

Comment: Here's a separate question: Let's say that there were 5 categories, one of which was `NaN`. How would I could NaN values as a separate category? `df.groupby("franchise")['items'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)` wouldn't do this.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang - I think the easier is replace `NaN` to some category and then count it. `df['items'] = df['items'].fillna('nan_cat')`

Comment: all pure pandas solution remove NaN, only works `(df.groupby("franchise")['items'].apply(Counter).unstack(fill_value=0).astype(int))`

Answer (score 4):

You could include the `items` column in the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), then use [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html).

```
>>> df.groupby(['franchise', 'items']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

items        bird  cat  dog  fish
franchise                        
franchise_A     0    1    3     0
franchise_B     1    0    0     1
```

---

**(*Rough*) Benchmark**

```
%timeit df.groupby(['franchise', 'items']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop

%timeit (df.groupby("franchise")['items'].apply(Counter).unstack(fill_value=0).astype(int))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.18 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby('franchise')['items'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.71 ms per loop
```